# How to read different tables from a HTML page using python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, datatables

I am using the html link below to read a table,

http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=1040645

I was able to read the table in first page using the code below but the issue is the page continues, So how can I read the table in next pages as well all together? I want to pull out all the records of the table regardless of how many pages.

Here is my attempt,

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

    url = 'http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=1040645'
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html,header=0)
    df = df_list[3]
    
    df
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

url = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=1040645&allcount={}"
page = 1
out = []
while True:
    try:
        t = requests.get(url.format(page), timeout=1).text
        df = pd.read_html(StringIO(t))[3]
        print("Page:", page)
        df = df.loc[1:, :]
        if len(df) == 0:
            break
        out.append(df)
        page += 25
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        continue

df = pd.concat(out)
df.columns = ["NUMBER", "NUMBER", "TYPE", "FILE DATE"]
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=None)
```

Prints:

```
                          NUMBER NUMBER                                   TYPE   FILE DATE
1                    ALT 867-90*    NaN                             ALTERATION  00/00/0000
2                    ALT 1078-83    NaN                             ALTERATION  00/00/0000
3                    ALT 2164-33    NaN                             ALTERATION  00/00/1933
4                    ALT 1307-67    NaN                             ALTERATION  00/00/1967
5                    ALT 1307-67    NaN                             ALTERATION  00/00/1967
6                     ALT 853-68    NaN                             ALTERATION  00/00/1968
7                    ALT 312-71P    NaN                             ALTERATION  00/00/1971

...
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Working good as expected. Thanks for your help. Just a quick question, what does that page += 25 actually do?

Comment: @TahsinAlam It's increasing the page counter, to advance the URL to next page...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium answer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import pandas as pd
url_base = r'http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=1040645'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(LINK_TO_YOUR_CHROME_DRIVER)

driver.get(url_base)

output = []

while True:
    df_temp = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, header = 0)[3]
    output.append(df_temp)
    
    next_page = driver.find_elements_by_name('next')
    if len(next_page) < 1:
        print("Complete")
        break
    else:
        next_page[0].click()
        
output = pd.concat(output)

driver.quit()
```